Is there away to pass a function id to the run.graphql query in Shopify?
Suppose I deploy multi discounts using the same function for shopify.
Is there away I can pass a discount id to run.graphql?
In example:
query RunInput {
  discountNode {
    metafield(namespace: "I want to pull a discount id, how can I pass it dynamically here?", key: "function-configuration") {
      value
    }
  }
}


Here is a modified code that can help you pass a discountID variable dynamically.


query RunInput($discountId: ID!) {
  discountNode(id: $discountId) {
    metafield(namespace: "your-namespace", key: "function-configuration") {
      value
    }
  }
}



Hope it helps!

How would I feed set hte variable $discountId and pass it to the run file?
